# Set NTFS / Sharing rights on a printer object

Tags: c#, .net, ntfs

I have a short question.

I want to change the sharing / ntfs rights of a printer.
The usergroup "everyone" should be removed from the share of the printer, and a named user should get access to that printer.

Is there any easy way without using acl?

Comment: Just did it with setACL.exe but this is really boring.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. NetAccessXxx might have been the original APIs for that, but they have been listed as unsupported as far as I can remember. Managing ACLs is messy but not that difficult, whether you do it programmatically or with command-line tools such as cacls or SetACL.

Comment: I hoped there is another answer :-(
.Net is so powerfull, but strikes down in such "simple" things which are needed every day...